# How to download a file via the Google Drive API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm working to download a file via the Google Drive API using the gem google-api-client.

```
x = Google::Apis::DriveV2
drive = x::DriveService.new
drive.authorization = auth

files = drive.list_files
files.items.each_with_index do |file, index|
    url_to_index = file.export_links.select { |k, v| v if k == 'text/plain' }
    file_content =  open(url_to_index["text/plain"]).read
end
```

The problem is file_content is returning the Google login screen not the file in text/plain format. It appears that when my Rails app opens the URL it does not have access to the text file.

What's the right way to enable my Rails app to grab the file in the text format?

Comment: Can you share what exactly was the encountered error that appears in the logs?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the log files. It's opening the URL, the url is just redirecting to the google sign in page, and not the requested txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stated in [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

> Depending on the type of download you'd like to perform — a file, a Google Document, or a content link — you'll use one of the following URLs:
>
> - Download a file — [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) with `alt=media` [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)
> - Download and export a Google Doc — files.export
> - Link a user to a file — webContentLink from the file resource
>
> **Downloading the file requires the user to have at least read access. Additionally, your app must be authorized with a scope that allows reading of file content.**

You may go through the documentation for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

See the log output: Two factor autentifications need to you permit access from you app to your google drive account.

In log you will see needed info to do this: link and secret_key.

```
tail -f log/*.log
```

Comment: How do I permit access from my app?

Comment: Doesn't my app already have permission. I'm using a omniauth strat to authenticate the user which is how I'm getting the file list.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that mimetype for download is different from the file meta.
Please check this url for available mimetype :  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open

for example mimeType : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
'